# When i am defining array with the required values it's throwing error in shell script

Tags: shell, scripting

When i am defining array with the required values it's throwing  below error

```
db_backup_daily.sh: 103: /home/user/Desktop/db_backup_daily.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting "fi")
```

The code which I have provided is getting executed in online shell editor but the same thing when I am trying to execute from my terminal it throwing error

```
#!/bin/sh
year=$(date +"%Y")
month=$(date +"%B")
day=$(date +"%d")
db_backup=/home/user/Documents/db_backup
YEAR_DIR=/home/user/Documents/db_backup/$year
MONTH_DIR=/home/user/Documents/db_backup/$year/$month
DAY_DIR=/home/user/Documents/db_backup/$year/$month/$day

FILE_NAME_ARRAY=( USER_TABLE_FILE PMT_TABLE_FILE FBA_PO_TABLE_FILE VENDOR_SUPPLIER_TABLE_FILE )

LOG_FILE_NAME_ARRAY=(USER_TABLE_LOG_FILE PMT_TABLE_LOG_FILE FBA_PO_TABLE_LOG_FILE VENDOR_SUPPLIER_TABLE_LOG_FILE)

TABLES_NEED_To_BACKUP=(Add_task checklist_task_management)

echo 'code executed successfully'
```

above code should get executed from the terminal

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between sh and bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725296/difference-between-sh-and-bash)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#!/bin/sh` means this script is meant to be run on the system's default POSIX shell, which is not always a link to bash/ksh, thus not guaranteed to support arrays. You need to change it to:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Comment: What i need to do @oguz ismail?

Comment: Thanks @oguz ismail . I changed the syntax for the sh

Comment: Sure @oguz ismail . Finally came to know the difference.